# Is there any way to connect Athena database to django

Tags: django, database, dashboard, amazon-athena, django-pyodbc

I am working to build dashboard on tables of athena. I have tried django-pyodbc in database settings but it is not working.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You question is a little too broad and would benefit on more background information as well as example source you tried and error messages you are getting. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include your `DATABASES` in settings, and what stack you are using. We need to know which `django-pyodbc` you are using (there are several, please include a link to the GitHub), what version of pyodbc, what version of Django, and what driver you're using at a operating system level. Oh, and what operating system are you running Django on? :)